# Using Chrome Console, can't find file linked to the error

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, debugging

I have a website called [lcee.fr](http://lcee.fr) (which run under WordPress/Divi Theme), when loading this site on Chrome, I see this error (among others):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'varsHost' of undefined
>                static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-730716.js?sv=6:4
>
> ```
> at window.hjBootstrap (static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-730716.js?sv=6:4)
> at static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-730716.js?sv=6:7
> ```

So, the links shown are those: http://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-730716.js?sv=6:7 AND http://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-730716.js?sv=6:4

BUT I can't see where in my WordPress Code those files are called, I have tried to search into the code for the string "hotjar", "static.hotjar.com" and other things but I did not find any file related to this.

Answer (score 0):

You will not find this in your code cause it is being called from outside by your HotJar plugin, the error seems to be on the JavaScript part of this plugin.

If you research errors like yours, a simple reinstallation or update of the plugin should resolve.

BTW, i tried to simulate on my chrome browser, your site uploaded normally.

if you don't remember what your plugin is about you can check this link: https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009340247-WordPress

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that I don't have any plugin named "HotJar" on my website, here is the list of all the plugin I have: "Akismet Anti-Spam", "Child Theme Configurator", "Elegant Themes Updater", "Image Tighten", "Kimili Flash Embed", "Velvet Blues Update URLs" and "WP Cost Estimation & Payment Forms Builder", and if I desactivate all those plugins the error is still there ^^

Comment: Ok @ailauli69, can you use the https://prnt.sc/ and link a print screen of the error for me ?